# Fill shaped(sized) pandas Dataframe with values randomly by stat count value. Reverse action for .count()

Tags: python, pandas, random

I need a `DataFrame` with `r` rows and dynamic number of columns(based on groups).
Input `count` column specifies how many `True` values are expected in the new `DataFrame`. My current implementation creates a temporary `DataFrame` with a single row containing a `True` value for each `group` in df, and then `explode()`'s that temporary dataframe. Finally, it groups by `count` and aggregates to result df

### input

--

```py
| group | count | ... 
|   A   |   2   |     
|   B   |   0   |     
|   C   |   4   |     
|   D   |   1   |
```

And i need to fill new `DataFrame` with this values **randomly** (**`c`**-(columns) value is dynamic same as names)

### expected output

--

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | **True** | **True** |
| **True** | NaN | **True** | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | **True** | NaN |
| **True** | NaN | **True** | NaN |

I think it's possible to add a randomized set of length from 1 to **`r`** and after expanding and etc. just agg(sum) by this values.

### my code

--

```py
inputs = [
    {"group": "A", "count": 2},
    {"group": "B", "count": 0}, 
    {"group": "C", "count": 4}, 
    {"group": "D", "count": 1}, 
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(inputs)

def expand(count:int, group: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """expands DF by counts"""
    count = int(round(count))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([{group: True}])
    # I'm thinking here i need to add random seed
    df1 = df1.assign(count = [list(range(1, count+1))])\
             .explode('count')\
             .reset_index(drop=True)
    return df1

def creator(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """create new DF for every group value(count)"""
    dfs = [expand(r, df['group'].values[0]) for r in list(df['count'].values)]
    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    return df
    
df.groupby('group', as_index=False)\
    .apply(creator)\
    .drop('count', axis=1)\
    # and groupby my seed
    .groupby(level=1)\
    .agg(sum)
```

I tried to declare my questions if it will be helpful:

1. Is there any method in pandas to make this easy/better?
2. How can I make random counts and assign them in the `expand()` function?
3. Is it a way to create sized `DataFrame` with `NaN` and then just drop there my values randomly(like `pd.where` or something)?

PS: This is my first time asking a question, so I hope I have provided enough information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure *pandas* solution would be to use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) :

```
out = pd.DataFrame(
    {g: [True]*c + [np.nan]*(R-c) for g, c in df.to_numpy()}
).sample(frac=1)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

      A   B     C     D
0  True NaN  True   NaN
1   NaN NaN  True   NaN
2  True NaN   NaN   NaN
3   NaN NaN  True  True
4   NaN NaN  True   NaN
```

---

*Old answer :*

A simple approach would be to *bootstrap* a pre-null [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) while randomly choosing/picking a coordinate `[index, column]` :

```
np.random.seed(0)

R = 5 # <-- rows

out = pd.DataFrame(
    np.nan, index=range(R), columns=list(df["group"])
)

for g, c in df.to_numpy():
    out.loc[np.random.choice(out.index, c, replace=False), g] = True
```

Comment: It's easily solved my problem:))) Thank you, it really saved me lots of time! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Step:

1. defining DataFrame from a list of dictionaries
2. `r` is number of rows in final DataFrame
3. A dictionary `group_indexes` is created, each key is a `group` name, each value is a random selection of unique row indexes. The number of indexes is the minimum of `count` and `r`.
4. empty DataFrame `df_empty` is created with `r` rows and columns defined by the unique `group` names.
5. iterating over each column in `df_empty`. If column name is in `group_indexes`, it sets the value in the column at those row indexes to be True.
6. `df_filled` is created by replacing all other non-True values in `df_empty` with NaN.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Step 1: initial DataFrame
inputs = [
    {"group": "A", "count": 2},
    {"group": "B", "count": 0}, 
    {"group": "C", "count": 4}, 
    {"group": "D", "count": 1}, 
]
df = pd.DataFrame(inputs)

# Step 2: Define the number of rows
r = 5

# Step 3: Create a dictionary with unique random indexes for each group
group_indexes = {group: np.random.choice(np.arange(r), min(count, r), replace=False) for group, count in zip(df['group'], df['count']) if count > 0}

# Step 4: Create an empty DataFrame with 'r' rows and columns defined by groups
df_empty = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(r), columns=df['group'])

# Step 5: Place 'True' in the DataFrame according to the indexes in group_indexes
for col in df_empty:
    if col in group_indexes:
        df_empty.loc[group_indexes[col], col] = True

# Step 6: Replace all other values in the DataFrame with NaN
df_filled = df_empty.where(df_empty, np.NaN)
```

Here is another and I think simpler approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initial DataFrame
inputs = [
    {"group": "A", "count": 2},
    {"group": "B", "count": 0}, 
    {"group": "C", "count": 4}, 
    {"group": "D", "count": 1}, 
]
df = pd.DataFrame(inputs)

r = 5  # specify number of rows here

# Create a DataFrame filled with NaN
df_filled = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(r), columns=df['group'])

# Randomly assign True values in each column based on its count
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['count'] > 0:
        random_indexes = np.random.choice(df_filled.index, size=min(r, row['count']), replace=False)
        df_filled.loc[random_indexes, row['group']] = True
```

This first initializes a DataFrame filled with NaN. Then for each group, it randomly selects unique indexes based on the group's count and sets those positions to True.